# Type Mismatch: Can not develop from element type object to string

Tags: java

here's a snippet of the code the issue is with the subkey.Keyset, it "Type Mismatch: Can not develop from element type object to string"

```
for(String msgtype : subkey.keySet()){
    int time = ((Integer)subkey.get(msgtype)).intValue();
    time--;

    if(time > 0){
        newsubkey.put(msgtype, Integer.valueOf(time));
    }
}
```

this bit above is the part of the code below where the error consists "subkey.keySet

```
public void run(){
    if(this.running){
      return;
    }
    this.running = true;

    while(this.running){
        synchronized(LOCK){
            if(msglist.size() != 0){
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                HashMap newmsglist = new HashMap();

                for(String player : msglist.keySet()){
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    HashMap subkey = (HashMap)msglist.get(player);

                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    HashMap newsubkey = new HashMap();

                    for(String msgtype : subkey.keySet()){
                        int time = ((Integer)subkey.get(msgtype)).intValue();
                        time--;

                        if(time > 0){
                            newsubkey.put(msgtype, Integer.valueOf(time));
                        }
                    }

                    if(newsubkey.size() > 0){
                        newmsglist.put(player, newsubkey);
                    }
                }

                msglist = newmsglist;
            }
        }

        if(this.running){
            try{
                sleep(this.sleepTime * 1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    this.running = false;
}
```

Comment: A `.keySet()` returns a Java `Set`; your keys must be a `String` type

Comment: So the keys in subKey are not Strings... What is your question exactly?

Comment: Very new to java just need to know how to fix the error @Machina

Comment: The errors fix @Manu

Answer (score 1):

Don't suppress warnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
HashMap subkey = (HashMap)msglist.get(player);
```

You effectively say here "Let's suppose that subkey is a map from Objects to Objects."

Two lines later, you expect to get String keys.

No wonder the compiler is confused.

Comment: Okay sorry, well I've fixed that problem now I have one where it says The method getInstance() is undefined for the type MsgThread @Ingo

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not suppress warnings! They are there to help you avoid mistakes like the one you are making here.

A HashMap is a standard java collection object that allows elements of arbitrary type (called the key) to be mapped to another set of elements again of an arbitrary, definable type (called the value).

Whilst the actual mapping procedure is based off object hashes, the ability to map arbitrary typed keys to arbitrary typed values is ultimately facilitated by generics. I suggest you [read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) if you don't know what they are.

What it boils down to is that, if unspecified, the HashMap will be mapping `Object` keys to `Object` values. Whilst this HashMap will technically be all inclusive in terms of mapping, you are losing type information as you put elements into the HashMap (where they are stored, very vaguely, as elements of type `Object`).

When you tried to retrieve the key set of the map and iterate over it using an enhanced for loop, the compiler realizes that it cannot safely cast a set of type `Object` to individual `String` objects (i.e. `Object` is not equal to or a subclass of `String`) forcing the compiler to throw said error.

To fix, all you need to do is specify a more specific type to the HashMap like so:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> subkey;
```

or in your case:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> subkey = msglist.get(player);
```

*assuming `msglist` is a map with type signature `Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`*

or:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> subkey = (HashMap<String, Integer>) msglist.get(player);
```

if `msglist` is a map with type signature `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Thank you very much for putting your time into that means a lot :D would really appreciate it if you could look at this for me https://github.com/kalo121/Issuekalo/tree/master and tell me why getInstance is saying The method getInstance() is undefined for the type MsgThread and how would I go about defining it? @CPU Terminator

Comment: @Noongrboy Whilst being completely off-topic in regard to this question, I did have a look at your code and I am unable to find it's declaration or import statement anywhere at all (MsgThread). I simply cannot determine or even infer the type of object it is and thus cannot help you. If it is some class you've created yourself, try to debug the class yourself and if you're really in a snag, post it as a separate question. **Include** the relevant segments of code, **describe** your problem specifically and **demonstrate** effort already made towards solving the issue at hand.